# Redefining cardinality of an element of a complex type. Is it possible?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I want to use a predefined complex type with a modified cardinality on one of its element. How can i do that without using override/redefine (I don't want to split the xsd file). Is it even possible ?

Example : in the case of an event, I want the birth date of the organizer (person_type) to be mandatory. But for each guests (person_type as well), it has to be optional.

I've tried to use restriction/extension but it doesn't fit my needs.
It obviously works using 2 complex type (i.e person_type1/birth_date 1..1, person_type2/birth_date 0..1) but it is king of ugly.

How can I use the complex type "person_type" in the guest element with cardinality change on birth_date ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:complexType name="event_type">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="event_name" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="organizer" type="person_type"/>
         <xs:element name="guests_list">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="guest" type="person_type" maxOccurs="99"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="person_type">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="first_name" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="last_name" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="birth_date" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:element name="event" type="event_type"/>
</xs:schema>
```

In order for this file to be valid :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event>
   <event_name>Party !!</event_name>
   <organizer>
      <first_name>John</first_name>
      <last_name>Doe</last_name>
      <birth_date>01/01/1970</birth_date>
   </organizer>
   <guests_list>
      <guest>
         <first_name>Jane</first_name>
         <last_name>Doe</last_name>
      </guest>
      <guest>
         <first_name>Foo</first_name>
         <last_name>Bar</last_name>
      </guest>
   </guests_list>
</event>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm increasingly inclined to use XSD 1.1 assertions for this kind of thing. It's much more convenient than using restrictions and extensions.

Specifically, define the complexType to be liberal, and then define context-dependent constraints in an xs:assert on the relevant element declaration.